# Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have such a problem, does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions

Comment: It seems you're using some other desktop environment. I won't expect GNOME specific things to work for other DE.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem after customizing my desktop many time I tried to solve it  and i got it.

The problem comes from desktop customization when you download `lightdm` from `gdk3` it will change your gnome setting and stop it from your PC/Laptop.

The solution is:

1. just update your laptop: `sudo apt-get update`
2. logout from top-right corner.
3. Then clik on setting icon below of user login.
4. then Select on `gnome/gnome-clasic/ubuntu/`  (whatever option you want to select)
5. then enter the password and login
6. optional --> remove unwanted application which you have installed to solve this problem.

thanks if you facing problem then comment here.

Comment: This didn't seem work. I'm on Linux Mint. I don't see any option for `/gnome/gnome-classic/ubuntu/`